# Django and jquery - after .load() form is no longer valid

Tags: jquery, django, forms, load, submit

I am using jquery .load() to load a django template into a popup div

the template I am using has a form and when I load the template the form is no long valid, but when I visit the template through the url the form is valid.

Can anyone think of any reason a form would no longer be valid after jquery load?

here is my form:

```
def createrecipe(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = RecipeForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                recipe = form.save(commit=False)
                recipe.original_cookbook = request.user.cookbooks.all()[0]
                recipe.pub_date = datetime.datetime.now()
                recipe.save()
                user = request.user
                cookbooks = user.cookbooks
                cookbook = cookbooks.all()[0]
                cookbook.recipes.add(recipe)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/account')
        else:
            form = RecipeForm()

        return render_to_response('cookbook/createrecipe.html',
                                    {'form':form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

here is my form template:

```
{% block content %}
<div id="createform">
<h1>Create New Recipe</h1>
    <form action="." method="POST">
        <table>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

here is the load function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".create").on("click", function(){
        $("#popupContact").load("/cookbook/createrecipe #createform");
    });
});
```

thank you,

snackerfish

Comment: Can you expand on "no longer valid"? Is it the form validation routine that is barfing, or ...? One thing to check:  1) load the form by itself and snapshot the HTML of the generated page (View Source, copy, paste), 2) load the page & form, and make another snapshot. How do they differ?

Comment: well after comparing the two, it doesn't seem like the source code on the jquery loaded page includes any POST form whereas form by itself does have the POST FORM

Comment: Ah ha! The game is afoot! :-)

Comment: haha thanks peter do you have any idea what could be causing this? the form shows up within the popup div as I would expect it to but does nothing

Comment: Got a link you can share? I'm a big fan of debugging the concrete as opposed to the abstract. I'm also a big fan of Firebug whenever there's JS lurking in the shadows.

Comment: as of now it is all being developed on localhost since it is a django project but maybe i could copy the templates and js into a pastebin or something

Comment: i think what is causing it is that since it is an ajax request (i believe .load is) i am not checking to see if the POST is type xhr because ajax is all a bit hazy for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's your submit button executed via jQuery or by default form behavior, i think that your code doesn't sees the loaded form you should use jquery's .on() method when handling ajax data. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I switched the .click to .on(click, function()) and still have the same problem

Comment: use it like this $("first-selector").on("click", "other", function ... your first selector is always present by the time javascript loaded "other" is your dinamicaly loaded selector.

Comment: it doesnt seem like my form is valid even though it was before i was using .load function

Comment: i dont understand what my first selector or my dynamic selector would be. can you please elaborate? i have updated what I now have as .on function thanks